# Is it possible to restore data already deleted from Trash in Mac?

Tags: macbook, data-recovery, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can items deleted from “Trash” be recovered?](https://superuser.com/questions/144931/can-items-deleted-from-trash-be-recovered)

I have a macbook pro with Tiger installed. I want to restore data that is already deleted from Trash, and the data is also from a year ago. Is this still possible? using 3rd party software maybe?

thanks

Comment: **the data is also from a year ago** This is beyond optimistic!

Comment: answers from Sathya's comment are exactly what you're looking for. Short answer, after that long, not a chance.

Comment: I'm unaware that in a year, there have been quantum leaps in the way files are organized and written onto the disk have changed significantly. If so, please enlighten me with a cite able reference. @Nifle

Comment: @Sathya - I think his best bet is a time-machine.

Comment: @Nifle absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a year, it is quite doubtful that you'll be able to retrieve any useable data from any of these files.

And the issue is not that you've re-arranged the drive, it's that the probablitity that a cache file, or another transistory file hasn't override a block that use to be attached to one of those files is minute.  Once the block is overwritten, even by 1 byte of data, it's virtually impossible to recover that file...

But, certainly give it a try...

FileSalvage is a undelete / data recovery tool, http://subrosasoft.com/OSXSoftware/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1

That offers a trial mode - No Registration Number - Trial Mode

> Without a registration number it is only possible to start using a version
>   of FileSalvage with limited functionality. In Trial Mode the user
>   will be able to scan for files but will be unable to recover them. For
>   full recovery functionality, the user must register his or her version of
>   FileSalvage. To do this, purchase the software online or via a retail
>   channel, and then simply select "Register" from the FileSalvage drop
>   menu and enter a valid registration number in the dialog screen.

And there's a number of other data recovery tools that are available for low cost...